# kendo: Enable / Disable button in navigation bar

Tags: kendo-ui

Below is a definition of the navigation bar, part of a view template that is used among several screens:

```
    <div data-role="layout" data-id="app">
        <header data-role="header">
          <div data-role="navbar">
              <a class="nav-button" data-align="left" data-role="backbutton">Back</a> 
              <span data-role="view-title">Title</span>
              <a class="nav-button" data-align="right" data-role="button" data-click="doneTapped" id="btnDone">Done</a> 
          </div>
        </header>
    </div>
```

The "Done" button is only needed on some screens, so it gets hidden when the main page loads:

```
    $("#btnDone").hide();
```

Hiding the button works fine, but showing it again does not work:

```
    $("#btnDone").show();
```

The button does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$("#btnDone").hide();` and `$("#btnDone").show();` use:

Hide button:

```
$("#btnDone").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

Show button:

```
$("#btnDone").css("visibility", "visible");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that has worked for me in this situation is to put a class on the button I want to show/hide instead of relying on the id:

```
<div data-role="layout" data-id="app">
    <header data-role="header">
      <div data-role="navbar">
          <a class="nav-button" data-align="left" data-role="backbutton">Back</a> 
          <span data-role="view-title">Title</span>
          <a class="nav-button btnDone" data-align="right" data-role="button" data-click="doneTapped" id="btnDone">Done</a> 
      </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

And then use the class to hide it:

```
$(".btnDone").hide();
```

Hope this works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Salam,

Try the following:

```
 <!--Home-->
    <div id="tabstrip-home"
         data-role="view"
         data-init="app.home"
         data-title="Home">

        <!--Header-->
        <header data-role="header">
          <div data-role="navbar">
              <a class="nav-button" data-align="left" data-role="backbutton">Back</a> 
              <span data-role="view-title">Title</span>
              <a class="nav-button" data-align="right" data-role="button" data-click="doneTapped" id="btnDone">Done</a> 
          </div>
        </header>

        <!--Content-->
        <div class="view-content">
          <h1>Hide / Show Navbar Elements</h1>
            <p>
              <center>
                <a data-align="left" data-role="button" data-click="app.show">Show</a>
              </center>
              <br />
              <center>
                <a data-align="left" data-role="button" data-click="app.hide">Hide</a>
              </center>
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>
```

In the data-init="app.home" function you find the navbar, then the leftElement and have references to them then you can control it, Example:

```
var navbar = null;
var left = null;
global.app.home = function (e) {
  navbar = e.sender.header.find('div[data-role="navbar"]').data('kendoMobileNavBar');
    left = navbar.leftElement;
    console.log(left);

};

 global.app.show = function (e) {
  left.show();
};

 global.app.hide = function (e) {
  left.hide();
};
```

Please see a working example here: http://jsbin.com/EpInoQOq/1/edit

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The way I handled hiding and shwowing the Back Button on different views was to use 2 different Layouts. This worked well for my use case as I only show the back button on 1 page:

```
        <!--Default Layout with Main Menu and no backbutton-->
        <div data-role="layout" data-id="layout">

            <!--Header-->
            <div data-role="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <span data-role="view-title"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--Footer-->
            <div data-role="footer">
                <div data-role="tabstrip">
....
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Layout with Back Button-->
        <div data-role="layout" data-id="layoutBackButton">

            <div data-role="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <a data-role="backbutton" data-align="left">
                        <!-- data-bind="isVisible: showBackButton" -->
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg"></i>
                    </a>
                    <span data-role="view-title"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My Remote View that uses the Back button then specifies the other Layout:

```
<div         data-layout="layoutBackButton"
             data-role="view"
...>
```